# Moments of a PDF expressed as sum of Gaussian pdfs

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $f({x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iN({x};\mu_i,P_i)$, where

$$N(x;\mu_i,P_i) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\sqrt{\det(P_i)}}\exp\Big[\frac{-1}{2}(x - \mu_i)^TP_i^{-1}(x - \mu_i)\Big]$$

and $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 1$ and $\alpha_i \ge 0$ for all $i$.

How do I prove that the mean $m$ and covariance $R$ of $x$ are

$$m = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i\mu_i\ \text{ and }\ R = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_iP_i + \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i(\mu_i - \mu)(\mu_i - \mu)^T\ ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $X_i\sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_i,P_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and let the $X_i$ be independent.

Let $B_i\sim\mathsf{Bern}(\alpha_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ with $B_1+\cdots+B_n=1$.

Let $(B_1,\dots,B_n)$ and $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be independent.

Let $X:=B_1X_1+\cdots+B_nX_n$.

Then $f(x)$ is the PDF of $X$.